# How do Microsoft (and other software companies with a large installed base) manage patch dependencies?

Tags: patch, hotfix

OS (usually security-based) patches and hotfixes that Microsoft releases to the community normally consist of, in my understanding, a series of updated DLLs or other binaries.

How does Microsoft, and other companies like it, ensure that that hotfixes don't clash with each other?  Do they always go for a cumulative patch approach, where a single hotfix will includes all of the fixes in previous hotfixes?  This doesn't *seem* to be the case, because many hotfixes seem to be focused on fixing specific problems.  If they are focused hotfixes, how do they prevent one hotfix from trashing another one (e.g. incompatible DLLs being installed with each other).

I have always admired Microsoft's ability to manage this process.  The company I work for is much smaller, and when I worked on the patch process a few years ago, we always went for the cumulative approach, where a single patch immediately superseded all previous patches based on that release.  This meant that the patches got progressively larger in size, until the next "official" release came out.

What are some good practices for managing patch dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, Microsoft Windows Installer has the ability to patch binaries directly.  Given known earlier states of a file, it can bring them to a known current state.  We used to do this for our Large Commercial Product, but after a couple of releases, it was taking upwards of 24 hours for our four-way systems to produce a patch - which isn't good when you have (or want to have) nightly builds.

After a while, we opted for cumulative fixes where we merely allowed upgrades.  We check that you're at a lower level, and then basically replace the entire product.  (We also had the case whereby the second or third "delta" was basically everything anyway.)

On Unix/Linux, we can't use MSWI, obviously, so we provide another installer which basically does the same thing: move all the files out of the way, install as if brand new, and then delete the backup.  The reality is, for us in our business, this is sufficient.  We haven't gotten any complaints that I'm aware of (and those complaints would hit me pretty quickly based on my current job) with people unhappy enough to actually call in and complain.  Mostly, they want to get the newer level with the patches so they can get on with their real business.  *Oddly enough, their business isn't installing patches.*